# Java NullException from a non-null value

Tags: java, exception, maps

I can't figure out why Java is giving me a NullPointerException when I'm trying to fill a map.

```
public class ResultsClass extends Class2 {

    private Map<String,Object> result_map;

    public ResultsClass(Object o){
        this.results = o;
        System.out.println(this.results.somemethod().isEmpty());
        fill_results();
    }

    private void fill_results(){
        System.out.println(this.results.somemethod.isEmpty());
        result_map.put("ID",this.results.somemethod()); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ResultsClass results = new ResultsClass(Object);
    }
}
```

Both of the print statements say false.

I think I'm just using the map wrong. I though .put put in a key value. I thought my declration of this as a <"string",Object> allowed me to mix and match values that will be put into the map. Even if I do:

```
result_map.put("id","value")
```

I get the same exception. Is there another type of map I should be using that can have may different key value types?

Edit:

Wow you guys are harsh. I did not know maps had to be declared as a class like this. I'm new and it didn't cross my mind. Thanks for the quick answer though!

Comment: You have not initialized map with new keyword.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug NullPointerExceptions. You should check each variable on the line that throws the NPE to see which one is null. If you did this, then you'd have known that your Map variable was null and you wouldn't have had to ask your question here. This is an important concept that you must learn if you are to progress and is much more important than the specifics of your question.

Comment: oh thanks, I'm not trying to learn, I'm just typing each piece of code line by line and posting it here. I love being belittled, so its a real best case scenario for me.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean to be belittling or even appear belittling. My only point that I want to pass on is that the process of solving NPE's is the key here and this process is much more important than the solution to your current problem, since once learned, most NPE solutions will become almost trivial for you.

Comment: I just started with Java and this was my first time using a map. I had some code thrown on me I've never seen before, and I'm not even a computer programmer. But I had to get this done. I tried outputting the things I thought where null but didn't even consider the map itself since I didn't realize it was a non-primitive type.

Comment: Not to worry. You will get better at all of this the more you do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate ("create") the map - for example:

```
private Map<String, Object> result_map = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
```

until you do, `result_map` is null (does not refer to a valid object) and can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't create the map; therefore you can't use result_map because it's null.